# Boolean: one operator and multiple objects

Tags: modifiers

Is there any option to use a boolean operator for subtracting faces on multiple objects?
I need to make a section of a lot of pieces and make it one by one it should be crazy....but I need to keep the object separated.
Is there any chance to have a non-destructive command?
Many thanks in advance for your support

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.91, a feature will be added to support boolean operations on collections. (Commit [ab7608af1bd4](https://developer.blender.org/rBab7608af1bd4)).

Comment: That’s an interesting patch - thanks for the link. However, isn’t that the opposite way around - using a collecting as the object to remove from this one. I think the question was to cut away a section of lots of objects.